# Changing non-translated fields in localized components

Tags: 2013, translation-manager, worldserver

I have product components which contain a mixture of fields, some of which are translated (by Translation Manager/World Server) and some not (like product SKU). Sometimes, the non-translated fields are changed in the localized components (for example a SKU variant for a particular localization), however if the component is re-sent for translation, these changes are lost - the component ends up with the translated fields, plus the original SKU from the parent component.

Is this "just the way it works" with Translation Manager, or is there some way to protect non-translated fields from being wiped on re-translation?

Comment: Sounds to me like a defect, I'd report it and see what the response on it will be.

Comment: @WillPrice: Is the non-translated field values on localized components are same as parent component field values? OR You want to maintain different values for non-translated fields on localized components

Comment: Different values - otherwise there would not be an issue

Comment: @WillPrice I added the idea for you at http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=5200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unfortunately "just the way it works".

You can file an enhancement request (which would obviously not do anything for the existing versions).

You can hook into the Tridion save event (TM identifies itself in the session, so you would know it's not a user saving). In this save event it is possible to read the old data and move over the fields that should not be changed.

Comment: Thanks Lars - indeed using the event system was my "Plan B"

Comment: By the way, how does TM identify itself in the session?

Comment: It sets Session.ContextData specifying an application ID "TranslationManager".